# How can I center tab labels in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I put the 3 label buttons (tab one, two and three) in the middle above the content? they are now aligned to the left. on top of that I would also appreciate a solution to hide the content in case a user is on his phone. I hope that this is not too hard.

```css
    .tabs {
      position:absolute; bottom:0;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .tabs label {
      order: 1;
      display: block;
      padding: 1rem 2rem;
      margin-right: 0.2rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #90CAF9;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: background ease 0.2s;
    }
    .tabs .tab {
      order: 99;
      flex-grow: 1;
      width: 100%;
      display: none;
      padding: 1rem;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .tabs input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
    }
    .tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
      background: #fff;
    }
    .tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab {
      display: block;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 45em) {
      .tabs .tab,
      .tabs label {
        order: initial;
      }
      .tabs label {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-top: 0.2rem;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="tabs">
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabone" checked="checked">
      <label for="tabone">Tab One</label>
      <div class="tab">
       <h1>Tab One Content</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtwo">
      <label for="tabtwo">Tab Two</label>
      <div class="tab">
       <h1>Tab Two Content</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabthree">
      <label for="tabthree">Tab Three</label>
      <div class="tab">
       <h1>Tab Three Content</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Add to `.tabs label` `text-align: center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flexbox's **`justify-content: center`** on `.tabs` with `width: 100%` to align the tabs in center of the page, like:

```
.tabs {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

For closing tab on mobile devices, use jQuery to remove the `checked` attribute from `#tabone`, like:

```
/* If mobile, remove checked attribute (Media Query in JS) */
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 45em)").matches) {
  $('#tabone').removeAttr('checked');
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below (*use full page view below to see it in center*):

```js
/* If mobile, remove checked attribute */
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 45em)").matches) {
  $('#tabone').removeAttr('checked');
}
```

```css
.tabs {
  position:absolute; bottom:0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tabs label {
  order: 1;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #90CAF9;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background ease 0.2s;
}
.tabs .tab {
  order: 99;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: #fff;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 45em) {
  .tabs .tab,
  .tabs label {
    order: initial;
  }
  .tabs label {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabone" checked="checked">
    <label for="tabone">Tab One</label>
    <div class="tab">
        <h1>Tab One Content</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtwo">
    <label for="tabtwo">Tab Two</label>
    <div class="tab">
        <h1>Tab Two Content</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabthree">
    <label for="tabthree">Tab Three</label>
    <div class="tab">
        <h1>Tab Three Content</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps, thank you! do you maybe also know how you can close all tabs when on phone?

Comment: @Sissy I've updated my answer, please have a look. Please let me know if this answer helps you out.

Comment: The jQuery part to close the tabs on mobile does not seem to work but I will accept your answer (I have to say that I never used jQuery but I added the line in my functions JS document)

Comment: @Sissy Have you tried running the code snippet above. Its working fine according to me.

Comment: Yes, what should the user do to hide the content? I tried this to test: $("tabtwo").click(function(){
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 45em)").matches) {
 $('#tabone').removeAttr('checked');

Comment: @Sissy No you just need to remove the `checked` attribute from `#tabone`. By again clicking on any of them will trigger the content back. I hope you understand.

Comment: @Sissy You are using wrong selector in your above comment. You are using `$("tabtwo")`, instead use `$('#tabtwo')`. You forgot to append `#` before the selector. jQuery will not able to understand what you are trying.

Comment: It works on page load now! :)is it also possible to hide all content again when you tap on the labels? so if I press on tab one when it is open it will hide all content again